# Numpy array assignment using another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is it possible to assign values to certain row indexes of Numpy array along column wise using another array? 
For example:

```
x = 
[[0,0],
[0,0],
[0,0],
[0,0]]

a = 
[[0],
[1],
[0],
[1]]

the resulting x after some operation, op(x, a) = 1, is

x=
[[1,0],
[0,1],
[1,0],
[0,1]]
```

Comment: how is `x` decided with `a`? What is some operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you require:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0,0],
[0,0],
[0,0],
[0,0]])

a = np.array([[0],
[1],
[0],
[1]])

for idx, i in enumerate(a):
    x[idx, i] = 1
```

Or, without a loop:

```
x[range(x.shape[0]), a.ravel()] = 1 

# x
# array([[1, 0],
#        [0, 1],
#        [1, 0],
#        [0, 1]])
```

Comment: Okay thanks I see, is there other way to do it without loop?